# Send a POST value only with PHP

Tags: php, post

I want to use my webpage to recognize if a *$_POST* is set and the, if it is, print it in the page, so this is what I really have now:

```
if (isset($_POST['error'])) {
    echo '<div id="error">'.$_POST['error'].'</div>';
}
```

But what I want is that, when an if statement that I have in the same document returns true, to send a POST request to that same file and so, show the error message with the *$_POST*. Is this possible or it is another easy way for doing it?

Sorry for not explaining so well, this is my code:

```
if (password_verify($_POST['oldpassword'], $result['password'])) {
    // Upload password to database
} else {
    // Set the $_POST['error'] to an error message so I can show it in the error DIV.
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the other IF statement you have that we understand how do you want to send POST request base on that?

Comment: What error message are you talking about? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want PHP to send a POST request, you need to use cURL (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Sorry for the bad info, updated my code! @Javad

Comment: Does all your code included in same php file? I mean both IF statements are in one php file?

Comment: @Javad Yes, they are on the same file.

Comment: OK check my answer, hopefully helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `$message` athe beginning of your page then handle the errors you want to show

```
$message = '';
if (password_verify($_POST['oldpassword'], $result['password'])) {
   // Upload password to database
} else {
   //set a proper message ID which will be handled in your DIV
   $message_id = 1;
   header('location: /current_path.php?message='.$message_id);
}
```

Now in the div you can show it as

```
if (!empty($_GET['message'])) {
   echo '<div id="error">';
   if ($_GET['message'] == 1) { echo 'First message to show.'; }
   elseif ($_GET['message'] == 2) { echo 'Second message to show.'; }
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work because I have first my error div and then, I have the if statement that assings the value to the `$message` variable.

Comment: Do you know what error message you want to show? I mean is it a static and fixed message or it's variable?

Comment: Oh, they are messages like 'The passwords are not matching' or 'The password has been successfully changed'. My idea was to create a function which would sent an `$_POST` to the same file where I am, and putting myself the message that I want. So it would be something like `sendErrorMessage('Password incorrect, re-enter it.')`. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @peregraum I updated my answer; please pay attention to `message=` in the created query string. Keep in mind that this method will refresh your page and posted values will be gone (if you want to keep them you may need to implement it by AJAX)

Comment: Oh, I've already thought about doing it with GET, but I'd prefer doing it with a POST. But if it's a very difficult thing, I could use the GET option.

Comment: If you could replace the position of IF statements it was possible to do it much easier; GET is easier than POST but if you want to use POST you need to use `CURL`